# Email Sends When I enter A Certain Part of my Page

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect, submit

I am having trouble with a contact form for my website. So there are two parts to this problem.

First I want to know how and why every time I enter the contact link of my page, it automatically sends an email, upon entering the page, and when clicking submit (I only want it to do this one) .

So example:
I go to mywebsite.com then I click on the 'Contact Us' link page. Upon taking me to the contact form, an e-mail is sent automatically. I am then allowed to fill out the form and send another e-mail. I want to know how to prevent that from happening and why it happens.

Second. I have seen lots of answered questions about this but none of the ones I have looked up on this website have worked for me so far.
When I click submit, to submit the form, it sends the email but then stays on the same page without clearing all fields or giving a confirmation message. I had also tried to redirect the page to say something like 'message has been sent successfully' or anything on the lines of that.

I am going to post my code below, but here are some notes on what I have tried before I do.

I tried to include a header to redirect after clicking submit. I am either doing that incorrectly or it just does not work.
I have tried the redirection with a java code, but since doing that it automatically sends an email then redirects to the page I stated without actually going to the contact form page.

My code is the php and html in one. I am going to separate the two after I finish it but I want to get it working first before I organize this section.
While looking at my code please do not judge. I am not a professional at this and I do understand that there are errors. I have tried to keep it with 0 errors but just have been adding code on top of code now to try and get this to work and may have added errors. I am open to suggestions in order to achieve the same effect while breaking down my code if possible. One error I do know I have is my form-inline statement. I am intentionally missing the quote at the end because with the quote, the search bar on my site gets messed up.

I have looked into jquery and ajax as well but I would prefer if someone give me a solution using the same format that I currently have the code in, unless the format is the problem I guess.

I changed my actual domain to mydomain.com for the example.

I do understand too that there may be a lot of irrelevant code but I am not sure if any line may be the problem so I tried to make clear what each section of code does for my page and included everything jsut in case one of those may be the problem.

```
<?php
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $numberErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $number = $comment = $subject = "";
    $datetime = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        }
        if (! preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
        if (! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
        if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
            $subject = "";
        } else {
            $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["number"])) {
            $number = "";
        } else {
            $number = test_input($_POST["number"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
            $comment = "";
        } else {
            $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
        }
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array(
            "content-type",
            "bcc:",
            "to:",
            "cc:",
            "href"
        );
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Full Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "E-mail: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: " . clean_string($subject) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "ipaddress: " . clean_string($ipaddress) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "date and time: " . clean_string($datetime) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone#: " . clean_string($number) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($comment) . "\n";
    $email_from = $name . '<' . $email_from . '>';

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:' . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */

    $myemail = "contact@mydomain.com";
    mail($myemail, $subject, $email_message, $headers);

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    sec_session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My Domain - Contact</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><img src="../tab/mydoaminlogo.jpg" alt="" width="780" height="104" /></h1>
    </div>
        <hr />
        <!-- end #logo -->
    <div id="header">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../index.php" class="first">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="../tab/News.php">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../tab/Locations.php">Locations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../tab/About.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../tab/Contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
                    <li><a href="../tab/Store.php">Store</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
                    <li><a href="../tab/login.php">LogIn</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
                    <li><a href="../tab/tab/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
                    <li><a href="../tab/register.php">Sign-up</a></li>
                </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
            </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
    <div id="search">
                <form method="get" action="" class="form-inline>
                    <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="s" id="search-text" size="15" />
                    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Search" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- end #search -->
        </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
        <!-- end #header-wrapper -->
        <div id="page">
            <div id="content_wide">
              <div class="post">
                    <div class="entrycontact">
                        <div class="container">  
                            <form id="contact" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                            <h4>Please fill out completely</h4>
                            <fieldset>
                                <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="<?php  echo $name;?>" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                                <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                            <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"tabindex="2" required>
                                <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <input placeholder="Subject" type="tel" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject;?>"tabindex="2" required>
                                <span class="error"><?php echo $numberErr;?></span>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <input placeholder="Number" type="tel" name="number" value="<?php echo $number;?>"tabindex="3" required>
                                <span class="error"><?php echo $numberErr;?></span>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." name ="comment" tabindex="5" required><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                            </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end #content -->
            <!-- end #sidebar -->
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #page -->
        <div id="footer"></div>
        <!-- end #footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell with the indenting but it looks like the `mail()` call is outside of the `
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` conditional which means it will run regardless of whether or not it's a post.  After formatting the code, this is what's happening.  It will call mail() every time.

Comment: @drew010. Everything starting from the  email_message line is outside of the $_SERVER statement. Should I add everything in or just the mail part?

Comment: @drew010 I added it that and everything around it inside the $SERVER braces but now it will not submit and just says error